# Create/update Product Policy via REST in Azure API Management

Tags: json, rest, put, azure-api-management

The documentation seems incomplete for "Create Or Update" product policy:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/productpolicy

[image: Microsoft Api Management REST API documentation]

As you can see, the "type" field is empty and there's nothing that indicates what should go in the body of the PUT operation.  Anybody have any idea of what should go in the body?  An example of usage would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TheDude, thanks for noticing, we will get this fixed.

Check out this documentation (which will give you details of Headers and Sample Body)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-product-entity#a-namesetpolicya-set-policy-configuration-for-a-product

Comment: I get the following error when I use the xml content type:  Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"ValidationError","message":"Resource was 
modified since last retrieval.","details":null}}
At D:\PowerShell Scripts\AddPolicyRest.ps1:31 char:9
+         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Header @{ "Authoriza

Comment: I get the above error even though I'm using api-version 2016-10-10:  "https://devimsapim.management.azure-api.net/products/54321/policy?api-version=2016-10-10"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it turns out the fix for the above answer was to simply add a "If-Match:*" to the request headers.  So, whenever you UPDATE or DELETE, you have to add an "If-Match" value to the request headers.